# Consistency of snapshot code in rtc?

Tags: rtc

A snapshot named `snapshot 1` is created for a Stream on Jan 1 2017 (For example)

Later I create  a stream out of `snapshot 1` and do some code delivery. (On Feb 2017)

After a month, I create another stream out a `snapshot 1`. (March 2017)

Will the `snapshot 1` have the same code as created on Jan 1 2017 ?

Comment: Could you please review your past question and accept, meaning clicking on the tick for the answer you think address your past questions? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). That helps other to know which answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the snapshot 1 have the same code as created on Jan 1 2017 ?

Yes, that is the idea behind a snapshot: it is immutable... unless tou delete it ([which is possible since RTC4.0](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/148115/how-to-delete-a-snapshot-using-scm-command-line-version-403)) and recreate one with the same name.

But if you have not deleted it, a snapshot content never change.

Comment: Is baseline similar to creation of tag?

Comment: @user3302323 there is no tag in RTC, but you can create baselines. A baseline is like a tag set on all elements of a components. If you have multiple components, you would create multiple baselines. A snapshot is like a tag but for *all* components on one stream (instead of component by component)

Comment: @user3302323 I see you still have not accepted any answer for your past answer: if you think they are not fully answered, leave me some comments and I will complete said answers.